# How to Authenticate at Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to authenticate an application GAE by webservice.

My steps are:

1. [Take the token](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html) - OK
2. Authenticate an application at GAE.

This way:

GET
http://myapp.com/_ah/login?continue=http://myapp.com/&auth=tokenIsHere works fine.

But when I try to make a new request

GET
http://www.myapp.com/api/list/&auth=tokenIsHere ..  401 Unauthorized.

But .. if I GET this way, it works:
http://myapp.com/_ah/login?continue=http://www.myapp.com/api/list/&auth=tokenIsHere

Which means that my token is correct, but my GAE authentication was unsuccessfully

Someone can tell me why?

Comment: Are you including the auth cookie in requests you make to your app?

Comment: @Nick Im reading and reading about, but I do not understand the cookie part.
Only the token is not enough? Why when I use the HTTP Requester (firefox plugin) I have successfully only with token

Comment: ...because FireFox automatically appends all cookies for you.

Comment: @Nick @Daniel May you guys tell me please, how can I make the cookie part? Im trying some like [that](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app)

Comment: @coffee When you go to /_ah/login, you pass in the token, and it returns a cookie (the 'ACSID cookie') which you then need to include in subsequent requests - otherwise the app has no way to know it's you. An easier/better option, though, would be to use OAuth!

Comment: @Nick


`for (Header header : httpResponse.getAllHeaders()) {
     if (header.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie"))
 System.out.println(header.getName() + " " +        header.getValue());
}`
I got this
**PREF=ID=6267d56y0970693f:FF=0:TM=1687329189:LM=1308888189:S=s4iJ6xdf4CIq9XE2; expires=Sun, 16-Jun-2013 16:46:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com**

Comment: @Nick http://www.myapp.com/_ah/login?auth=tokenIsHere

Comment: First I get an auth token from google, which is a temporary string, **then passing that token to the login page of my app, which in turn gives an authentication cookie**. Then add that cookie to the header of all of future http requests. So... **Where can I find this cookie?** I apologize if my question is too simple.

Comment: @coffee The token should be returned by the `/_ah/login` URL, in a cookie named 'ACSID'.

Comment: @Nick Thank you so much. I had found an example yesterday. See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post solved my problem: http://javagwt.blogspot.com/2009/12/authenticating-android-app-to-google.html

Comment: You should never prompt your users for their Google account credentials!

Comment: @coffee I don't see the connection. You should use OAuth, or ClientLogin.

Comment: Im using ClientLogin, as did the blogger
"https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";

Comment: @coffee Yes, but you shouldn't use it from the _server_ - the client should use it, not your server-side app. OAuth is a better choice now in any case.